# Is the Canon EF 70-200mm f/4.0 L IS lens hard to sell because people would prefer the f/2.8?

Tags: lens, canon, used-equipment

I have been trying to sell my Canon EF 70-200mm F/4.0 L IS USM Lens for ages now, but no one seems to want it. Could it be because the f2.8 is a better lens and people would rather pay the extra and get that rather that the f4?

Comment: It's a decent lens - assuming it's in good condition, my guess is that you're simply charging more money than folks are willing to pay for a used lens.  I also question whether this is on-topic since this isn't a question about photography or photo editing.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons, (not advertised to the right people, not got the right price, etc.) but you've not provided sufficient detail to allow a full answer. As currently worded, this appears to be off topic (I'm surprised that @ahockley didn't vote for closure).

Comment: I have the 70-200mm f/2.8L, and it is hands down my favorite lens (I have a Canon 24-105mm f/4L, a Canon 50mm f/1.4 and a Canon 16-35mm f/2.8L, all nice lenses, but can't touch the 70-200mm).

Comment: Everything sells at the right price. If it's not selling, lower the price until it does, or until you reach the point where you'd rather keep it.

Comment: Hi guys thank you for the feedback. I was trying to sell it on amazon marketplace, have since put it on ebay and taken some of your advice. It has some watchers already. Sorry for the off-topic post, and the vagueness, thank you for taking the time to replay :)

Comment: I am curious as to why you say the f2.8 is the better lens. Conversely, I could argue that the f4 is the better lens because it is half the price and weight, equally as sharp at f4, and I don't need the wider aperture. Both were built for different purposes.

Comment: You will have to pry my f/4 L from my cold dead hands. It is one of the best Canon L lenses: compact, lightweight, fast and sharp. And it is probably the least expensive L lens around.

Answer (score 9):

Since you did not tell us anything about how you are 'trying', I can't really give you a complete answer. Now, it is a good lens and has a nice price-point too.

Things to consider:

- Price. You need a to offer a discount compared to the lowest price from a reputable source. Check [BHPhoto](http://www.bhphoto.com) and [Adorama](http://www.adorama.com) if you are in the US, otherwise the local equivalent.
- Location: Craigslist, Kijiji and eBay are all places with lots of visitors.
- Description: Make sure the description of the lens is accurate in your ad. Don't complicate things but make it easy to find, specifying the range, full model name, etc.
- Patience: It takes me between 1 and 6 months to get a buyer sometimes on the listing sites. With eBay things are more pressing but it can take 2 or 3 tries.

Relative to that lens itself, it may be that this model being the middle of the line makes it less desired. The non-IS model is much cheaper and the F2.8 model is not that much more expensive. There is also competition from the Sigma 70-200mm F2.8 (OS and not) as well which is a very good lens and is reasonably priced.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you simply haven't found the correct audience, or it could be that your price is too high.

I personally would be happy with a f/4 version because for what I tend to shoot, I don't necessarily need the f/2.8 version, and I'd prefer to save money and weight.

If you really want to sell it quick, you could go ahead and sell to a reputable dealer such as [KEH](http://www.keh.com/SellYourGear/sellyourgear-1.aspx). They aren't going to pay as much as a direct buyer might because they need to make profit, but they will pay pretty well.

At the moment, (assuming "Excellent", or 80-89% condition) it looks like they'd pay about $550.

Comment: The going rate on ebay is about $750 from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly prefer the f/2.8, but another issue may be that many people are hesitant about buying a used lens from an unknown source. When I switched from Canon to Nikon, I think I sold most of my stuff on Craigslist (which works out well because people can meet you to check out the stuff) and Ebay (but I have a high feedback rating).